# Adding Class Attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to add class in every send paragraph using jquery. Please see image below.
[image]

Comment: $('p:not(".postDate")').each(function() { $(this).addClass('posteExcerpt')});

Comment: @Shiladitya that gets all `p` elements. It doesn't exclude the `.postDate`

Comment: @Rory I edited the answer. Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.newsPostContainer p`, along with `:not()` to exclude the `.postDate` elements:

```
$('.newsPostContainer p:not(.postDate)').addClass('posteExcerpt');
```

Alternatively, if you can guarantee that the target `p` will always be preceded by `p.postDate`, then you can select by sibling:

```
$('p.postDate + p').addClass('posteExcerpt');
```

Comment: No, not to exclude the .postDate, what I want to happen is that in the next .postDate paragraph it will add class ".posteExcerpt". like this:<p class=".postDate"></p><p class="posteExcerpt"></p>

Comment: sorry I missed interpret your code. but, this one is correct. I tried and it works awesome! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the traversed 'P' tag has 'postDate' class or not, if not, this is the second 'P' tag and addClass to it.

```
$(".newsPostContainer").find('p').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('postDate'))
       $(this).addClass('posteExcerpt');
});
```

Realised, you can use `:not` too.

Comment: I tried this too and works awesome! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

`p.postDate + p` will select all `p` that is right after a `p.postDate`

```js
$(".newsPostContainer  p.postDate + p").addClass('posteExcerpt')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newsPostContainer ">
  <p class="postDate">postDate</p>
  <p>posteExcerpt</p>
  <p class="postDate">postDate</p>
  <p>posteExcerpt</p>
  <p class="postDate">postDate</p>
  <p>posteExcerpt</p>
  <p class="postDate">postDate</p>
  <p>posteExcerpt</p>
  <p class="postDate">postDate</p>
  <p>posteExcerpt</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the `each()`: `$('p.postDate + p').addClass('posteExcerpt');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan true, my mistake